# Getting hold of grid cell and clearing all controls in it

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have a grid with two columns and multiple rows, each cell containing a number of controls. Among these controls I have a button which should, when I press it, delete all the controls in the current grid cell. How can I get the index of the grid cell my button is in and how can I delete all controls in this cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you? you'll need to add a `using` statement for `System.Linq`

```
//get the row and column of the button that was pressed.
var row = (int)myButton.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
var col = (int)myButton.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);

//go through each child in the grid.
foreach (var uiElement in myGrid.Children)
{ //if the row and col match, then delete the item.
    if (uiElement.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty) == col && uiElement.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty) == row)
            myGrid.Children.Remove(uiElement);
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work. The first two lines are doing their job, but the Linq part, the third row of code seems to give the problem. If you could probably explain what it does, then I could try to figure out the reason. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, take your grid.children, and foreach child in grid.Children, if they are in the same row and column as your button, delete it. You can actually probably combine it into 1 statement. Ill update the original post

Comment: Yes, after your comment this is exactly what I did, but it doesn't really work. After it deletes the first child, in the second loop, it gives me an InvalidOperationException in the foreach loop. Any idea? Thanks again!

Comment: You can't remove an item from a collection while iterating the collection in a foreach loop (that's why you get the InvalidOperationException).  If there's only going to be one match, store a reference to it when you get the match, `break` from the loop, then call Remove.

Comment: No, there are several matches, because I have multiple controls in the grid cell.

Comment: You could probably do it like it was before then: add each item that matches the row/column into a list. Iterate through the new list, calling myGrid.Children.Remove on them.

Answer (score 1):

using linq and extending the previous answer, notice the ToList() so you can immediately remove the element

```
//get the row and column of the button that was pressed.
var row = (int)myButton.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
var col = (int)myButton.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty);

//go through each child in the grid.
//if the row and col match, then delete the item.
foreach (var uiElement in myGrid.Children.Where(uiElement => (int)uiElement.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty) == col && (int)uiElement.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty) == row).ToList())
{
    myGrid.Children.Remove(uiElement);
}
```